# SurrealDB: describe the table

Tags: surrealdb

In MySQL, we would do something like: `SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name>`.

How does one achieve the same using `surrealQL` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the INFO command in SurrealQL instead: https://surrealdb.com/docs/surrealql/statements/info

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).